# Sql query to be converted into HQL or Criteria

Tags: hibernate, hql, criteria-api

Below is the sql query which will fetch the results which is  a combination of many inner joins..and the corresponding pojos are

```
Table             JAVA POJO
boopUSER          User
booprtyu         rtyu
```

user.java contains the following properties

```
updatedby
updatebby
updateddate
```

rtyu.java contain the following properties

```
 id;
code;
name;
```

The query which fetches the record..

```
SELECT distinct u.name, u.updated_by, u.updateddate FROM boopUSER u, boopuser_rtyu ug, booprtyu gwhere u.id = ug.user_id and ug.rtyu_id = g.id and u.ACTIVE_FLAG='Y' and g.id not in (10,11) order by u.name
```

now could ypu pls advise equivalent hql or criteria for this.Thanks in advance, early help would be appreciated

Answer (score 0):

HQL and Criteria can be applied only to hibernate mapped entity (and related association).
Your pojo are not hibernate entity (I think that because classes are not annotated) so the only way is to use native SQL and mapping result to POJO (see [Native SQL](http://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/orm/3.3/reference/en/html/querysql.html#d0e13904))